Replacing Vanity Countertop
I am looking at replacing my bathroom vanity countertop and wall to wall it is 36", is I a problem to order a counterop that is exactly 36"?

They say measure twice and cut once.   Measure again front and back.  Having both the same measurement makes fitting in touchy, might need force.  A difference of 1/16 to 1/8 inch gives some wiggle room.

cut a sheet of cardboard to verify fit ... it may reveal out of square walls

Good idea, thanks!

Often you can scrape out a bit of the wall to make it fit. Cut a piece of wood  so that its length exactly matches width of the vanity and see if you can shove it in.

You should also check how square the space is.
